# Frequency collision and crosstalk error

Tags: quantum-state, noise

As the number of qubit increasing, the frequency of qubit will be crowded and there will become the frequency collision. I was wondering that is there any relation between frequency collision and crosstalk error? Does frequency collision lead to crosstalk error? If not, what's the difference between them?